# Use TP-Link Archer C7 as extra switch and wireless AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I am definitely not an expert when it comes to home networking. The current wireless setup in my home is as follows: I have one device from the internet provider in the house that acts as router, switch and wireless AP (range 192.168.0.*). That's it, plain simple, and it is quite satisfactory in the house. However, the possible number of settings on this device is quite limited (e.g. I cannot configure a DHCP range, only a subnet)...

Today I tried to extend the wifi range to the garden terrace. I bought a TP-Link Archer C7 V2 router and connected the in-house device and the Archer through a cable both on the LAN ports. I disabled DHCP and NAT on the Archer and configured a static LAN IP for it. This seemed to work over a cable. Then I wanted to have the same wireless network SSID both in house and in the garden. So I configured the exact same wireless settings on both devices (same SSID, same key, same security settings, but a different channel).

When I am in the garden, everything works fine. I get an IP address in the correct 192.168.0.* range, I can access the Archer through its configured static IP address, and I have internet access. Same still in the house.

However, when I go from the house to the garden while connected to the wifi, my computer picks up the right AP, but something goes wrong with the DHCP, I think. Internet access is gone, and my computer gets a self-assigned IP address in the 169.etc range and no gateway, not entirely correct... It is only after I configure a static IP for my computer that everything works. After that I can switch back to DHCP.

Some thoughts on this? What have I done wrong?

EDIT: I just tested on my Android smartphone with Wifi Analyzer, and all seems to work just fine. Nice AP switches and it gets the right IP Addresses... My Macbook Pro on the other hand: still issues...